# Testing interaction across multiple simultaneous browsers?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to figure out if there is a good way to test an application where a considerable amount of the complexity is in ensuring that changes made in one browser to a document are correctly pushed to the other people viewing that document, without them having to refresh the page.

Does anybody know of a reasonable way of automating a test for this? I'm using rspec with capybara currently.

Comment: I think the best approach might be to do some edits, and check that the server is notified correctly, then load the page with the old data and send it the events that were generated by the previous step?

Answer (score 1):

you can try http://www.phantomjs.org/